# Two primary keys in a table, databases, SQL, Cracking the Coding Interview Chapter 14

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am reading Cracking the Coding Interview these days. Chapter 14 is about Databases and SQL. There is a paragraph called "SQL Statements". Please write in your answers if you have the book and read the paragraph. It introduces several tables, which will be used in an example. One of them "StudentCourses" has two columns which are both used as primary keys.

How can this be the case? How can a table have two primary keys? I use MySQL and tried to create all the tables with roles out of The Simpsons (the TV Series), but of cause this doesn't work for StudentCourses. Does anyone know what the author meant by that example or how I should go about this problem?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: A table can only have one primary key. This primary key can be a "composite key" if it includes more than one column.

Comment: *which are both used as primary keys* - more likely that they both contribute to being a single primary key

Comment: Maybe Caius Jard is right. She introduces several tables. before that she mentions that the colums which are marked by a star "indicate a primary key". Both columns in the table I mean are used in different tables as well. So maybe it is like a reference ...

Comment: Sounds like a typical table denoting a many to many relationship. A course has multiple students and a student can take multiple courses so this would be modelled by a table with columns for CourseId, StudentId and a composite primary key including both columns

Comment: It's written using incorrect grammar for the meaning. "has two columns which are both used as primary keys" means each column is a primary key, but that's not what it's trying to say. It should be written as "has two columns that are used together as the primary key". The most import change there is from "primary keys" to "the primary key" (there can be only one). Martin's comment describes the situation well.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks for you comments and edits. The solution is that the keys are composite primary keys and foreign keys. So I had to reference this from the other tables. What helped me was the comment of Martin Smith and this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SydCFe5eF4o
Thank you!

In my point of view the author should have made this more clear.

The solution to create the right table is:

create table StudentCourses

(CourseID int(11),

StudentID int(11),

primary key (CourseID, StudentID),

Foreign key (CourseID) references Courses(CourseID),

foreign key (StudentID) references Students(StudentID)
);

Btw.: Did nobody of you guys read the book?!